# Removing old / unused docker images

Tags: sonatype, nexus3

I'm using Sonatype Nexus as a Docker Registry and after a while, it got really big (new image with every CI build and some old projects).

I tried using "Purge unused docker manifests and images" task, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

I remove the old docker images manuely.

1. get nexus-cli

   wget https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/nexus-cli/1.0.0-beta/linux/nexus-cli

   chmod +x nexus-cli
2. configure host

   ./nexus-cli configure
3. show images

   ./nexus-cli image ls
4. keep the latest 5 images

   ./nexus-cli image delete -name mlabouardy/nginx -keep 5
5. A clean script

> ```
> image_file=image.txt
> CLI_HOME=/data/nexus3
> KEEP_VERSION_NUM=5
>
> $CLI_HOME/nexus-cli image ls > $image_file
> sed -i '$d' $image_file
>
>
> cat $image_file | while read line
> do
>     echo "start clean image:  $line"
>     $CLI_HOME/nexus-cli image delete -name $line -keep $KEEP_VERSION_NUM
> done
> ```

6. create  **create docker - delete unsued manifests and images task**
7. create  **create admin -compact blob store task**

Comment: whatever that script is, its getting a access denied at the moment

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup a [Cleanup Policy](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/repository-management/cleanup-policies).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a cleaning policy (for example: 15 days after modification)
   - Caveat: `docker push` of the same hash is *not* modification

For each your registry (Nexus calls it "repository of type Docker"):

- Setup the cleaning policy of your choice
- The cleanup task

  - Create
  - Run until finish
  - Check the nexus3.log file
- The "remove unused manifests and images"

  - Create
  - Run until finish
  - Check the nexus3.log file
- The "compact blob" task

  - Create
  - Run until finish
  - Check the nexus3.log file
- The space should be freed now
- Don't use Nexus in your next project
- ...
- Profit

Comment: What would you suggest instead of Nexus?

Answer (score -7):

For removing old and / unused docker images you must use below command:

`docker images purne`

documents: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

Comment: This only works for local docker images. My question was regarding Sonatype Nexus repository. My repository is taking too much images and I'm wondering how to purge/clean it.